# exit from sage without ;1R

Tags: sage

I'm writing my first code in Bash. I'm coding a program that starts opening Sage, and after that closes, it opens R.

In my Sage script, I use `quit()` for exit to the program, but when that happens, a `;1R` is added on the command line:

[image]

and so, I cannot continue to execute the commands that make Bash open R. How can I avoid that?

I'm using Sage 7.6 and Linux version 4.4.0-66-generic (buildd@lgw01-28) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017

Comment: I would guess it doesn't come from sage but from your Bash script calling it. Can you show it ?

Comment: I go first into the file in which sage is installed ($ cd .../sage-7.6) and after I call sage with ./sage ($ ./sage)

Comment: Can you show your script, or a simplified version of your script, so that other users can replicate the problem. See [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: R 
    source('/home/alheli/Bureau/Scripts_CDHB/R1.R')
    q()
    y

    cd Documents/SAGE/sage-7.6
    ./sage
    attach('/home/alheli/Bureau/Scripts_CDHB/Pol_roots.sage')
    quit()

    cd
    R

    source('/home/alheli/Bureau/Scripts_CDHB/R2.R')
    Results

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and add the script there, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This sequence is printed on the screen due to an ansi sequence

```
ESC[6n
```

or

```
^[[6n
```

Per https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797, this sequence is for the following purpose

```
request cursor position (reports as ESC[#;#R)
```

If you don't care about the text that's on this line, you could use `grep -v` to eliminate it:

```
./runcmd.sh | grep -v "\[6n"
```